# addListenerForSingleValueEvent doesn't fire

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Trying to check of user logging in exists in database but on first run `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` does not fire.

```
private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredentials(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {    
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                //String dbUrl = "https://doctalk-f0b75-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/";
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                if(user!= null){
                    //final DatabaseReference mUserDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(dbUrl).child("user").child(user.getUid());
                    final DatabaseReference mUserDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user").child(user.getUid());
                    Log.v(TAG, mUserDB.toString());

                    mUserDB.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        String path = mUserDB.getRef().toString();
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            if (!snapshot.exists()) {
                                Map<String, Object> userMap = new HashMap<>();
                                userMap.put("phone", user.getPhoneNumber());
                                userMap.put("name", user.getDisplayName());
                                mUserDB.updateChildren(userMap);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) { throw error.toException();}
                    });

                    mUserDB.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            if (!snapshot.exists()) {
                                Map<String, Object> userMap = new HashMap<>();
                                userMap.put("phone", user.getPhoneNumber());
                                userMap.put("name", user.getDisplayName());
                                mUserDB.updateChildren(userMap);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) { throw error.toException(); }
                    });
                }
            }
            userIsLoggedIn();
        }
    });
}
```

Couldn't figure out why...

**UPDATE:**

I think there is something related to location and db url.
I'm getting db url = `https://app-name-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/`
Where db url on console is `https://app-name-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/`

And as mention in [google docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start#write_to_your_database):

> Note: To get a reference to a database other than a us-central1
> default dstabase, you must pass the database URL to getInstance() (or
> Kotlin+KTX database()) . For a us-central1 default database, you can
> call getInstance() (or database) without arguments.
>
> You can find your Realtime Database URL in the Realtime Database
> section of the Firebase console. It will have the form
> https://.firebaseio.com (for us-central1 databases) or
> https://.firebasedatabase.app (for databases in
> all other locations).

Comment: The first step is to stop ignoring possible errors, and implementing `onCancelled`. At its minimum it should be `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`.

Comment: As Frank van Puffelen mentioned in his comment if you try to log the databaseError, is there something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: I have added `throw error.toException();` but nothing is printed in the logcat. Debugging it seems that listeners are created but skipped...I don't understand why user is created in `Authentication` but not inserted to db???

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, your:

> FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

and

> final DatabaseReference mUserDB =
> FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user").child(user.getUid());

it is not taken properly

Comment: I am getting the user from `mUserDB` so I assume it is connecting when authenticated. Only thing I find weird is that `path` points to `https://app-name-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com` where as google docs say to point it to the specific location it was created at.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Realtime database has now two locations.

1. US
2. Belgium

US DB URL is an old one and Belgium URL contains an extra node.
If your firebase console contains Belgium URL means you are created a database instance in Belgium. So re-download the google services JSON file and use it.